# Escaping entire XML for a webservice response

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee

I have a Java Restful webservice that returns out an userdetails xml as below:

```
<userdetails>
    <firstName>first</firstName>
    <firstName>last</firstName>
    <email>123@gmail.com</email>
</userdetails>
```

Any of the fields in the XML can contain special charecters which will cause issues for the client when they use Jaxb to convert xml into java object.

I can use "StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml" to escape special charecters in a field like say for firstName and it is escaping it correctly.

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(firstName);
```

But I have to do this for every field in my XML. Is there any way where I can escape the entire XML at once instead of doing it for every field.

Comment: Any xml encoder should handle the escaping for you automatically.

Comment: been using jaxb to do the marshalling and unmarshalling....it does not complain on the server side...but at the client side, issues are being noticed for fields with these special charecters during unmarshalling

Comment: what issues?  how is the client side parsing the xml?

Comment: client is using jaxb as well....so when they try to unmarshall xml into java object, they are seeing issues becoz of these special charecters

Comment: what issues are they seeing?

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to traverse all text elements, escaping them in the process (below code taken from [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0625.html) and slightly modified):

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class EscapeXml {
  static String inputFile = "data.xml";
  static String outputFile = "data_new.xml";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
              .newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(inputFile));

    // locate the node(s)
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList)doc.getElementsByTagName("*");

    // escape text nodes
    for (int idx = 0; idx < nodes.getLength(); idx++) {
      Node node = nodes.item(idx);
      if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int cIdx = 0; cIdx < childNodes.getLength(); cIdx++) {
          Node childNode = childNodes.item(cIdx);
          if (childNode.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            String newTextContent =  
              StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(childNode.getTextContent());                
            childNode.setTextContent(newTextContent);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // save the result
    Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    xformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(new File(outputFile)));
  }
}
```